# Handling keyboard interrupts within a Linux kernel module to launch an user space application?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kernel-module, interrupt-handling

As a part of my kernel programming project I have to write a kernel module which can handle a keyboard interrupt and launch an user space application to show that my module is handling the interrupts properly. Is is possible to do? As I don't know how to execute an user level application from kernel space?

Comment: If you talk about **Linux** kernel, there is `call_usermodehelper()` function, which calls user level program.

Answer (score 0):

call_usermodehelper() does help you do that, but it is able to execute binaries at command line level. for e.g. /usr/bin/logger can help you log some text in syslog. I am not able to launch any GUI based applications using call_usermodehelper().